# DolphinDB HttpClient error message "url must be a string scalar"

Tags: httpclient, dolphindb

I got the following error message when using HttpClient in DolphinDB:

```
url must be a string scalar
```

Does anyone know what to do with this error message? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin version needs to match the DolphinDB server version. Right now the plugin version is 130 so you need to get server version 1.30